# Running a python module using -m from within eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I have written a python package within eclipse and, up until recently, I was running my code exclusively within eclipse. The main for my code was within the file that contains the top level class after the usual

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

section.

I have now packaged my code up as a whl and, to enable me to call the whl from the command line I have moved the main into an __main__.py and call my package from the command line with the command:

```
python -m <<my package>> -c config.txt
```

I'm convinced that the solution is simple, but I can't figure out how to call my package within the pydev debugger. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible, you just have to turn on the preference on the PyDev preferences to launch with the `-m` flag.

i.e.: go to: `Preferences > PyDev > Run` and check `Launch modules with python -m mod.name`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's possible I'm not thinking this through properly but I'm still not clear. I have installed my module using pip install <module>. and can run it from the command line with the command "python -m <<my_module" -c config.txt". Can I do the same within Eclipse and have the module running under the debugger?

Comment: Humm, sorry, I had understood something different... for that, no, you need to provide the actual .py file (in menu: `Run > run configuration > Main Module`). It can be the file you installed in your interpreter, but it still needs the actual .py file, not just the module name.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Fabio